# How to share useState in different components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, i18next

I followed this tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmCnx0YnBs4&t=265s&ab_channel=TravelsCode) to create a translator in my app.

I'm trying to use it in another component:

languagePicker.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import translate from "./i18n/translate";
import { I18Provider, LOCALES } from "./i18n";
import { useBetween } from "use-between";

import App from "../App";

const LanguagePicker = (props) => {
  const { locale, setLocale } = useBetween(App);
  return (
    <I18Provider locale={locale}>
       <div>
            <button onClick={() => setLocale(LOCALES.ITALIAN)}>italian</button>
            <button onClick={() => setLocale(LOCALES.ENGLISH)}>english</button>
            <button onClick={() => setLocale(LOCALES.GERMAN)}>german</button>
            <p>{translate("hello")} </p>
          </div>
    </I18Provider>
  );
};
export default LanguagePicker;
```

but of course, in this case, it change the language just in the component itself.
My app.js is like this:

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState(LOCALES.ENGLISH);

  return (
    <I18Provider locale={locale}>
        <div>
          <Header />
          
        <Footer />
    </I18Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do; If I use the buttons in App.js, works fine, otherwise will work just in the component.
Hope you can help me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share state between components, the recommended way is to use Context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

In short, crete a js file with where you export a React.createContext()

```
export const LangContext = React.createContext()
```

Then wrap your application in provider

```
<LangContext.Provider value={}>{children}</LangContext.Provider>
```

Then grab the state from the context by getting the context in the component

```
const context = React.useContext(LangContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Context Providers are scoped. As you have two `I18Provider`, one wrapping the content of your app (giving global access to your locale state) and another on your `LanguagePicker`, the `I18Provider` of `LanguagePicker` is scoped only for component wrapped by it.

You want to expose the `setLocale` which maybe provided by a [hook](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook) that your `I18Provider` library exposes or wrap the provider in a Context Component and expose it your self.

A good example of this is written up here [Kent C Dodds: How to use React context effectively](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively)

For i18next a hook is provided:

```js
const { i18n } = useTranslation();
i18n.changeLanguage('en-US');
```